# Conditional expectation on Cross product von Neumann algebra

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Let $(M,G,\alpha)$ be a $W^*$-dynamical system. Let $G$ be discrete. Then the cross product von Neumann algebra $M\rtimes_\alpha G$ is defined in the Hilbert space $l^2(G,\mathcal{H})$. Now since $G$ is discrete we can write $l^2(G,\mathcal{H})=\oplus_{g \in G} \mathcal{H}\otimes \epsilon_g $ where $\epsilon_g$ is defined as $\epsilon_g(h)=\delta_{h,g}$. Using this identification we can write any element of $\mathcal{B}(l^2(G,\mathcal{H}))$ as matrix of operators on $H$.

Now let $P_g$ be the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $H\otimes \epsilon_g$ of  $l^2(G,\mathcal{H})$. Then I saw a result (link given below), that the map $\phi: M\rtimes G \rightarrow M$ defined by $\phi(T)=\sum_gP_gTP_g$ where the sum is in the SOT topology is a conditional expectation.  Interms of matrix representation of $M\rtimes G \subset \mathcal{B}(l^2(G,\mathcal{H}))$, I guess that the map $\phi$ is mapping a matrix to its diagonal? Is it true? How to prove it? Why does the sum infact belong to $M$?

https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2373237.pdf

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178241528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never mention how you define $M\rtimes_\alpha G$. In the direct sum picture, one defines, using the matrix units $\{E_{gh}:\ g,h\in G\}$,
$$
M\rtimes_\alpha G=\Bigg[\Big\{\sum_{g\in G}\alpha_g(x)\,E_{gg}:\ x\in M\Big\}\cup\Big\{\sum_{h\in G}E_{h,g^{-1}h}:\ g\in G\Big\}\Bigg]'',
$$
where $\hat x=\sum_{g\in G}\alpha_g(x)\,E_{gg}$ is how we see $M$ inside $M\rtimes_\alpha G$. The elements $u_g=\sum_{h\in G}E_{h,g^{-1}h}$ are unitaries, and the algebra $\hat M$ of elements $\sum_{g\in G}\alpha_g(x)\,E_{gg}$ is invariant under conjugation by each $u_g$.

The expectation is indeed "compression to the diagonal" in a block sense. And the "diagonal"  is $\hat M$. In this notation, the projections are $E_{gg}$. Then
$$
\sum_{g\in G} E_{gg}\Big(\sum_{s\in G}\alpha_s(x)\,E_{ss}+\sum_{r\in G\setminus\{e\}} c_{r}\sum_{t\in G}E_{r^{-1}t,t}\Big)E_{gg}=\sum_{s\in G}\alpha_s(x)\,E_{ss}\in\hat M.
$$

---

To see that $\phi$ is normal, suppose that $T_\alpha\nearrow T$, selfadjoints. Given a vector $x=\sum_g x_g$, where $x_g=P_g x$,
\begin{align}
\|\phi(T-T_\alpha)x\|^2
&=\Big\|\sum_gP_g(T-T_\alpha)P_g\sum_hx_h\Big\|^2\\[0.2cm]
&=\Big\|\sum_gP_g(T-T_\alpha)P_g x_g\Big\|^2\\[0.2cm]
&=\sum_g\|P_g(T-T_\alpha) x_g\|^2\\[0.2cm]
&\leq\sum_g\|(T-T_\alpha) x_g\|^2\\[0.2cm]
\end{align}
Now because $T-T_\alpha$ is uniformly bounded and $\sum_g\|x_g\|^2<\infty$, given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $F\subset G$, finite,  such that $\sum_{g\in G\setminus F}\|(T-T_\alpha)x_g\|^2<\varepsilon$. Then
$$
\limsup_\alpha\|\phi(T-T_\alpha)x\|^2
\leq \varepsilon+\limsup_\alpha\sum_{g\in F}\|(T-T_\alpha)x_g\|^2=\varepsilon.
$$
This shows that $\phi(T_\alpha)\to\phi(T)$ sot, and so $\phi$ is normal.

Comment: Then any $T \in \mathcal{B}(l^2(G,\mathcal{H}))$ can be represented as a matrix of operators on $H$ as $T=[T_{gh}]$ where $T_{gh}=P_gT|_{H_h}$. Is this representation correct?  How does if $S=\sum_gP_gTP_g$ where the sum is in SOT topology, becomes the diagonal matrix obatined from $T$? I could understand it in the finite dimensional setting.  Suppose $T_i$ converges to $T$ in SOT topology, how can we express the convergence interms of this matrix representation.

Comment: When you say "diagonal", you mean "block diagonal". As for convergence, I don't think you can. Seeing operators as infinite matrices is way less useful than it is in the finite-dimensional case.

Comment: What I mean to be by diagonal is that, the matrix of $\sum_gP_gTP_g$ has non zero entries only in $(g,g)$^th position for all $g \in G$ and that entry is nothing but $T_{(g,g)}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. $P_g$ is the matrix unit $E_{gg}$.

Comment: How to show that $\phi$ is normal?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. I've edited the answer.